# Magento 2 - Overriding cart slider template

Tags: magento2

I'm a front end developer and recently started working with Magento 2. Currently I'm Working with Magento 2.2.6. and trying to override Cart Slider template which is I found in my theme Magento_Checkout > template > minicart > content.html
I have made some structural changes, and then run the compile command, but I'm unable to see my changes. The file in pub>static>... folder doesn't reflect my changes. Not sure what I am doing wrong in compiling the code

Comment: Try after delete that file from `pub/static/frontend/{Theme Vendor}/{Theme}/{Website local}/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html`

Comment: Did the same, but my structure wasn't there, same default structure showing.

Comment: it should in `Magento_Checkout> web > template > minicart > content.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your override Cart Slider template which is I found in my theme Magento_Checkout > template > minicart > content.html it is wrong.

Please override your **content.html** file at location `magento2/app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/`

**After run below commands:**

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

**For eg:**

> app/design/frontend/Stack/arpixel/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html